# Changing names of properties while Serializing to JSON without source code

Tags: java, json, serialization

Need to serialize java objects to JSON while doing compression such as name change, exclusion etc. Objects use class from jar, source code of which is not available.

Looked through many libraries([Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) , [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)), but found none solving this particular problem. Most of them are annotations based, which I can't use given I don't have source code.

One way to solve this problems is, use reflection and recursively go through object until you find a property name of which should be replaced or object is excluded in serialized JSON.

Need solution for this. Better if it is already implemented and tested.

Comment: You could write wrapper classes for those objects.

Comment: By wrapper class, do you mean, replicating each and every property in my classes and then adding annotations to same?

Comment: Yes. If there are too many classes it may not be practical. Check if [Castor](http://www.castor.org/features.html) is suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to the problem.

Google gson has class called [GsonBuilder](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) which has methods for [exclusion strategy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setExclusionStrategies%28com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy...%29) and [naming strategy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setFieldNamingStrategy%28com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy%29).

Using these two methods implemented a custom solution, where all the mapping and exclusion rules are stored using a xml and used at the time of serialization and de-serialization.

Works perfectly, though not sure about the performance of same.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/.

You can rename and filter with quite concise code:

```
// renames all "fieldOfName" to "toName", excludes from serialization 
// and deserialization fields named "fieldNamed" and declared in DefinedInClass
// and uses fields with all visibility (protected, private, etc)

Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().rename("fieldOfName", "toName")
                                    .exclude("fieldNamed", DefinedInClass.class)
                                    .setFieldFilter(VisibilityFilter.ALL)
                                    .create();

genson.serialize(myObject);
```

- If you want to do some more complex filtering (based on annotations for example) you can implement [BeanMutatorAccessorResolver](http://genson.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/owlike/genson/reflect/BeanMutatorAccessorResolver.html) or extend [BaseResolver](http://genson.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/owlike/genson/reflect/BeanMutatorAccessorResolver.BaseResolver.html).
- Same for property renaming you can implement [PropertyNameResolver](http://genson.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/owlike/genson/reflect/PropertyNameResolver.html) and have full control.
- And finally if you want to filter fields, methods or constructors according to their modifiers you can define your own [VisiblityFilter](http://genson.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/owlike/genson/reflect/VisibilityFilter.html).
- Concerning performances of filtering/renaming there should be no problem as it is done only once per class and then cached.

To start using Genson you can have a look at the [Getting Started Guide](http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will have a look at it, but very little chance that I will use this....Though this will be helpful for somebody else....