# Java: Gson change property name without serialization

Tags: java, json, gson

Is it possible to change the name of a Json property without serialization with Gson?  For example, given this Json

```
{
   "1": {
      ...
   },
   "2": {
      ...
   }
}
```

could I change the `"1"` to a `"3"` without removing its contents.  I know that the `addProperty` method adds a new property, or overwrites an existing property with a new value, but I want to change the name of a property without affecting its value.  Also, pasting the existing value as the second argument of `addProperty` will not suffice.

**EDIT:** To add more context, I will explain the bigger picture.  I have a JSON string that is a couple thousand lines long.  I'm writing a program leveraging Gson in order to change the values in that JSON string.  I am at a point where I not only want to change the values of properties, but the names of the properties themselves.  I have done everything so far without serialization.

Here is a snippet of the Java I wrote:

```
String file = "\\temp.json";

FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

JsonStreamParser parser = new JsonStreamParser(reader);
// Parse entire JSON
JsonElement element = parser.next();
// Get root element
JsonObject sites = element.getAsJsonObject();
// Get first child element
JsonObject site1 = sites.getAsJsonObject("1");

JsonObject clust1 = site1.getAsJsonObject("CLUST");

for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    // "Dynamic" variable        
    String num = Integer.toString(i);
    // Get property whose name is a number, has siblings
    JsonObject one = custCluster1.getAsJsonObject(num);

    one.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("name", "cluster" + i);

    JsonObject subOne = one.getAsJsonObject("SUB");

    subOne.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("name", "aName" + i);

    for(int n = 1; n < 1002; n++) {
        // "Dynamic" variable
        String inst = Integer.toString(n);
        // Get property whose name is a number, has siblings
        JsonObject subSub = subOne.getAsJsonObject(inst);
        // If the property doesn't exist, then don't execute
        if(subSub != null) {

            JsonArray subSubArray = subSub.getAsJsonArray("SUBSUB");

            subSub.getAsJsonObject().remove("name");

            int m = 0;

            while(m < subSubArray.size()) {

                subSubArray.get(m).getAsJsonObject().remove("SR");

                subSubArray.get(m).getAsJsonObject().remove("FI");

                subSubArray.get(m).getAsJsonObject().remove("IND");

                subSubArray.get(m).getAsJsonObject().addProperty("ST", "1");

                subSubArray.get(m).getAsJsonObject().addProperty("ID", "2");

                subSubArray.get(m).getAsJsonObject().addProperty("DESCR", "hi");

                m++;
            }
            m = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs to be more specific. It's hard for me to come up with an answer besides "you just change it". Where do you read/identify this "1" you want to change? Wherever/whenever you identify that node, you can change it using Gson can you not, just as you're doing in your code snippet with other nodes? **Edit** I see, you just want to change the name but `Gson` api doesn't seem to support that action. Is that right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619991/changing-names-of-properties-while-serializing-to-json-without-source-code may help

Comment: @mmcrae Yes that is correct. I'll check that out.

Comment: A lot of stuff I saw googling depends on serialization. But that's not an option for you because you are not the one generating this JSON - you receive it and must modify it. Correct?

Comment: @mmcrae That is also correct.  I thought about deserializing it and the serializing it again but that seems like overkill. The only problem I can see is how to integrate genson with the existing gson?  Or learn how to use genson and re-write?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with GSON / Jackson, but is there not a way to say `remove()` a node, and to `add()` a node? Here's my thought: `get` the value of the property you want to change `changeme`. Then, `remove()` property `changeme`. Then, `add()` a property with your `newname` and the old value from `changeme`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mmcrae for helping and suggesting this method.

Since I'm already saving the (key, value) pairs in variables, you can remove the property whose name you want to change from the parent, and then add it back with a new name and the content that was already saved.

Like this:

```
JsonObject sites = element.getAsJsonObject();

JsonObject site1 = sites.getAsJsonObject("1");

JsonObject clust1 = site1.getAsJsonObject("CLUST");

site1.remove("CLUST");

site1.add("NEWCLUST", clust1);
```

Comment: you can accept this answer as the correct one too. Congrats on one more problem solved!